# A simple "loss of $this" scope issue in JS/JQ .. explain?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to improve my JS skills and I've rewritten a bunch of code as a namespaced object literal (I think.)  But now I have a "this"-related problem.  Help me understand?

Here is abbreviated code.

```
var MYAPP = {

    init: function(){
        $(document).on("click",".showLove", MYAPP.showLove);
    },
    showLove: function(){
         var thisId = MYAPP.findId();
         $.post(//// do AJAXy stuff using thisId);
    },
    findId: function(){
        var thisClass = $(this).attr('class');
        var thisIdPos = thisClass.indexOf("id-")+3;
        var thisId = thisClass.substr(thisIdPos, 3);
        return thisId;
    }
}
```

So I'm sure you probably see the problem.  In the findId function $this is undefined and I get an error.  Earlier I had the findId logic in showLove and everything worked.  I moved the findId logic to it's own method because it was being used in a few different places.

So let me just ask this ->  Why does $(this) point to the correct element in 'showLove' .. but not in 'findId'?  Since 'findId' is called from inside 'showLove', shouldn't it have access to the same variables, including $(this)?  Is this my first "self = this" situation?

I know this is a basic question, but if someone could help me understand, I'd .. uh.. 'showLove'.

Comment: Have a look at this discussion for both your improvement and some alternatives to your use: http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-class-instantiation/

Comment: IF it would help, I could post a "reworked" alternative using your example and this function...let me know if you would find that of use, if not, no big deal :)

Comment: If you have the time that could be helpful.  I was really just using this approach as a way of namespacing and organizing my code. I just wanted to gather my "spaghetti code" and group it logically. It made sense to me to be calling MYCODE.methodGroupingNumber3.specificMethod.  But I realize now that I'm getting into an extra level of complexity re: OOP. So anything you would like to show would be appreciated.

Comment: check this fiddle out: http://jsfiddle.net/F7xVn/1/ - click the "Ya gotta" to see it in action...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing `MYAPP.showLove` to jQuery and saying "attach this function as a click handler to the document".

When you do this, `MYAPP.showLove` *forgets* it was attached to `MYAPP`, as you're only passing the *function*, with no reference to the namespace.

Therefore, when `showLove` gets executed as a click handler, `this` is no longer `MYAPP`. Normally when you detach a function from an object `this` becomes either `window` or `undefined` (ES5). However, jQuery decides `this` should be the `.showLove` element that was clicked, by using `call()` or `apply()`.

When you call `MYAPP.findId()` in `showLove` however, `this` is still set to `MYAPP`; as that's what `findId` is attached to (you're calling the method *on* `MYAPP`).

To fix this (no pun intended), you can either pass the value of `this` to `findId` (preferred, IMO), or use `call()`/`apply()`.

```
var MYAPP = {

    init: function(){
        $(document).on("click",".showLove", MYAPP.showLove);
    },
    showLove: function(){
         var thisId = MYAPP.findId(this);
         $.post(//// do AJAXy stuff using thisId);
    },
    findId: function(which){
        var thisClass = $(which).attr('class');
        var thisIdPos = thisClass.indexOf("id-")+3;
        var thisId = thisClass.substr(thisIdPos, 3);
        return thisId;
    }
}
```

or:

```
var MYAPP = {

    init: function(){
        $(document).on("click",".showLove", MYAPP.showLove);
    },
    showLove: function(){
         var thisId = MYAPP.findId().call(this);
         $.post(//// do AJAXy stuff using thisId);
    },
    findId: function(){
        var thisClass = $(this).attr('class');
        var thisIdPos = thisClass.indexOf("id-")+3;
        var thisId = thisClass.substr(thisIdPos, 3);
        return thisId;
    }
}
```

Comment: Best explanation.  Muy helpful.  Thanks for helping me figure that out.  I'll mark you as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the this, you need to do

```
MYAPP.findId.call(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

`this` in showLove comes from its instantiation in `$(document).on("click",".showLove", MYAPP.showLove);`

`var thisId = MYAPP.findId(this);` // pass it to the function

`findId: function(thisPassed){` and reference it by that name

One way to do it at least.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem relies in how are you invoking the **findId** function. Whenever you do this:

```
MYAPP.findId()
```

You are statically referencing the function, which will execute without the context of an object. If you want to keep that context you will need to invoke it like this:

```
MYAPP.findId.call(this)
```

By doing that your **this** variable inside findId will be bound to whatever object you are passing as parameter to the call function (in this case, the current **this**, hence you are keeping that reference)

On the side: I would recommend you to take a look at underscore.js' bind function, it is a really useful helper!